# How to assign to deeply nested Hash without using many 'nil' guards

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a nested hash, to which I need to add more deeply nested property/value pairs.

**Sample A:**

```
a = {}
a['x']['y']['z'] << 8
```

Normally I'd have to do this:

**Sample B:**

```
a = {}
a['x']           ||= a['x']           = {}
a['x']['y']      ||= a['x']['y']      = {}
a['x']['y']['z'] ||= a['x']['y']['z'] = []
```

Otherwise, I will get `undefined method '<<' for nil:NillClass`.

Is there some type of shorthand or function along the lines of code A instead of code B?

Comment: If you go in the opposite direction "`nil` guards" are not an issue: `h  = {  'z'=>:foo }; h = { 'y' => h }; { 'x'=>h } #=> {"x"=>{"y"=>{"z"=>:foo}}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most elegant solution for the deep-nested hash of any depth would be:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = h.dup.clear }
```

or, even better (credits to @Stefan)

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

---

That way one might access any level:

```
hash[:a1][:a2][:a3][:a4] = :foo
#⇒ {:a1=>{:a2=>{:a3=>{:a4=>:foo}}}}
```

The idea is to *clone the `default_proc` within the hash itself*.

Comment: Inventive! Inventive! (Had to write it twice because of minimum comment length.)

Comment: Alternatively `hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }`

Comment: @Stefan indeed, it’s even better (no redundant dup.) Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of ways that could be done.

```
arr = [:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :foo]
```

**Use [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`)**

```
def hashify(arr)
  arr[0..-3].reverse_each.reduce(arr[-2]=>arr[-1]) { |h,x| { x=>h } }
end    

hashify(arr)
  #=> {:a1=>{:a2=>{:a3=>{:a4=>:foo}}}}
```

**Use recursion**

```
def hashify(arr)
  first, *rest = arr
  rest.size == 1 ? { first=>rest.first } : { first=>hashify(rest) }
end

hashify(arr)
  #=> {:a1=>{:a2=>{:a3=>{:a4=>:foo}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To give a little backgroud, there's a method [`Hash#dig`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) which is present since ruby 2.3. With this you can safely attempt to *read* any number of keys:

```
{a: {b: {c: 1}}}.dig :a, :b, :c # => 1
{}.dig :a, :b, :c # => nil
```

of course, this doesn't solve your problem. You're looking for a *write* version. This has been [proposed but rejected in Ruby core](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11747) in the form of `Hash#bury`.

This method does almost exactly what you are looking for, however it can only set nested *hash values* and not *append to nested arrays*:

```
# start with empty hash
hash = {}

# define the inner array
hash.bury :x, :y, :z, []

# add to the inner array
hash[:x][:y][:z] << :some_val
```

You can get this method through the [ruby-bury](https://github.com/dam13n/ruby-bury) gem, or alternatively you can take their implementation from [their source code](https://github.com/dam13n/ruby-bury/blob/master/hash.rb)

Comment: Nah, gem! It’s a one-liner, check my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right I was just trying to show how it works the same as [] here. removed it.

Comment: @blackstone8 i appreciate that you accepted my answer, but I would consider accepting mudasobwa's instead. It's being more upvoted and is pretty clever.

Comment: I did as you asked but I understood your answer better and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to deeply set/initialize arrays/hashes using a list of keys. If they keys are ints, it assumes indexing into an array, otherwise it assumes a hash:

```
def deep_set(target, path, value)
  key = path.shift
  return target[key] = value if path.empty?

  child = target[key]
  return deep_set(child, path, value) if child

  deep_set(
    target[key] = path[0].is_a?(Integer) ? [] : {},
    path,
    value,
  )
end
```

Here is an example of using it:

```
target = {first: [:old_data]}
deep_set(target, [:first, 1, 1, :lol], 'foo')
puts target # {:first=>[:old_data, [nil, {:lol=>"foo"}]]}
```

It uses the fact that ruby allows you to set-and-expand arrays on the fly, which is a bit wonky, but works nicely here.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the [get](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash#rodashget-example) and [set](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash#rodashset-example) methods from the [rodash](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/Rodash) gem in order to set a deeply nested value into a hash with a default value.

```rb
require 'rodash'

a = {}

key = ['x', 'y', 'z']
default_value = []
value = 8

current_value = Rodash.get(a, key, default_value)
Rodash.set(a, key, current_value << value)

a
# => {"x"=>{"y"=>{"z"=>[8]}}}
```